# How to get months to show correctly in a morris.js chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I am having an issue getting months to show correctly in a morris.js chart.

```
<script>

var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

Morris.Line({
  element: 'morris-line-chart',
  data: [
          { m: '01', a: 0, b: 270 },
          { m: '02', a: 54, b: 256 },
          { m: '03', a: 243, b: 334 },
          { m: '04', a: 206, b: 282 },
          { m: '05', a: 161, b: 58 },
          { m: '06', a: 187, b: 0 },
          { m: '07', a: 210, b: 0 },
          { m: '08', a: 204, b: 0 },
          { m: '09', a: 224, b: 0 },
          { m: '10', a: 301, b: 0 },
          { m: '11', a: 262, b: 0 },
          { m: '12', a: 199, b: 0 },
        ],
  xkey: 'm',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['2014', '2015'],
  xLabelFormat: function (x) { return months[x.getMonth()]; }
});
</script>
```

but all months on the chart show as 'Jan' ...

Comment: [According to the documentation](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html) `xLabelFormat:` accepts Date objects, where you are providing strings.

Comment: So it isn't possible?

Comment: Instead of using strings, use date objects and return them as month strings .

Comment: The 01, 02 is output from SQL result. It must be 01, 02 etc. so the output is in order ... If I output as January, February then it won't be in order ...

Comment: the `x` in `xLabelFormat:` is intended to be a Date object, not a string. Currently, `months` is a string array. Just make those month strings Date objects instead. this has nothing to do with `data`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you [look at the documentation](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html), the **required** `xkey` option is defined like this:

> A string containing the name of the attribute that contains date (X)
>   values.  Timestamps are accepted in the form of millisecond timestamps
>   (as returned by Date.getTime() or as strings in the following formats:
>
> - 2012
> - 2012 Q1
> - 2012 W1
> - 2012-02
> - 2012-02-24
> - 2012-02-24 15:00
> - 2012-02-24 15:00:00
> - 2012-02-24 15:00:00.000

Currently, in your data, you are only supplying an int representing the month (ie 01, 02, 03, etc.)

So if you change your month data to be a valid timestamp string, according to the documents, you should then have a valid method for mapping the index of the returned "month" value to your `months` label array...

**Example:**

```js
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

Morris.Line({
  element: 'morris-line-chart',
  data: [{
    m: '2015-01', // <-- valid timestamp strings
    a: 0,
    b: 270
  }, {
    m: '2015-02',
    a: 54,
    b: 256
  }, {
    m: '2015-03',
    a: 243,
    b: 334
  }, {
    m: '2015-04',
    a: 206,
    b: 282
  }, {
    m: '2015-05',
    a: 161,
    b: 58
  }, {
    m: '2015-06',
    a: 187,
    b: 0
  }, {
    m: '2015-07',
    a: 210,
    b: 0
  }, {
    m: '2015-08',
    a: 204,
    b: 0
  }, {
    m: '2015-09',
    a: 224,
    b: 0
  }, {
    m: '2015-10',
    a: 301,
    b: 0
  }, {
    m: '2015-11',
    a: 262,
    b: 0
  }, {
    m: '2015-12',
    a: 199,
    b: 0
  }, ],
  xkey: 'm',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['2014', '2015'],
  xLabelFormat: function(x) { // <--- x.getMonth() returns valid index
    var month = months[x.getMonth()];
    return month;
  },
  dateFormat: function(x) {
    var month = months[new Date(x).getMonth()];
    return month;
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.5.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>

<div id="morris-line-chart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

**Edit**

The above example can be adjusted for bar charts by including morris version 0.5.1 (instead of 0.5.0 - according to the [github page about this issue](https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/issues/494) - I have not tested this in other versions) and slightly changing the `xLabelFormat` option (the `x` in `function(x){...}` apparently is a different object with bar charts vs line):

**Bar Chart Example:**

```js
// months array and data are left the same
// only change is that the labelFormat option is removed
// and, x in xLabelFormat is a different object with Bar charts vs Line

// [inspect console to see the object]

var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

Morris.Bar({
    element: 'morris-bar-chart',
    data: [{
        m: '2015-01',
        a: 0,
        b: 270
    }, {
        m: '2015-02',
        a: 54,
        b: 256
    }, {
        m: '2015-03',
        a: 243,
        b: 334
    }, {
        m: '2015-04',
        a: 206,
        b: 282
    }, {
        m: '2015-05',
        a: 161,
        b: 58
    }, {
        m: '2015-06',
        a: 187,
        b: 0
    }, {
        m: '2015-07',
        a: 210,
        b: 0
    }, {
        m: '2015-08',
        a: 204,
        b: 0
    }, {
        m: '2015-09',
        a: 224,
        b: 0
    }, {
        m: '2015-10',
        a: 301,
        b: 0
    }, {
        m: '2015-11',
        a: 262,
        b: 0
    }, {
        m: '2015-12',
        a: 199,
        b: 0
    }, ],
    xkey: 'm',
    ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
    labels: ['2014', '2015'],
    xLabelFormat: function (x) { // <-- changed
        console.log("this is the new object:" + x);
        var month = months[x.x];
        return month;
    },
});
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>


<div id="morris-bar-chart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. Is there a reason that it wouldn't work on a bar chart? I get `Uncaught TypeError: x.getMonth is not a function`.

Comment: [According to this GitHub page](https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/issues/494) `xLabelFormat` is only supported in morris-0.5.1 (the snippet is 0.5.0). I just quickly tested it and it works. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I still can't get this to work. I am trying to have a line chart and bar chart on both pages using `xLabelFormat`, it works on the line chart but when it gets to the bar chart it throws `Uncaught TypeError: x.getMonth is not a functionMorris.Bar.xLabelFormat @ (index):421(anonymous function) @ morris.min.js:6b.Grid.d.setData @ morris.min.js:6d @ morris.min.js:6d @ morris.min.js:6d @ morris.min.js:6(anonymous function) @ (index):400`. I have updated as suggested.

Comment: @Jack - the `x` in `xLabelFormat : function(x) { //... //}` is a different object in Line Chart vs Bar Chart. `months[x.getMonth()]` won't work in Bar because `x` is not a date like it is in Line. If you notice in the Bar example in this answer, the mapping works like this: `months[x.x]`...

Comment: @wahwahwah I have an issue regarding morris. My month are coming in the form of numbers from database like (1,2,3..). Thing is that for certain month values e.g 4 and 5 there are no values in my table. Now I want to display name of month rather than its number. I used your solution for this question, it worked. But now it includes those months also which does not actually have values. e.g if 4 and 5 are missing then it shows april and may on the graph. How I can get rid of this

Comment: @AmitKaushal - This should be a separate question, not a comment.